# how to build a job jar for hadoop Mapreduce job in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

I'm trying to run a mapreduce code example on AWS. This is the link for the code sample https://github.com/ScaleUnlimited/wikipedia-ngrams

However, I'm pretty new for these things. In fact, they did write in the Readme file that  I should build a job jar file from the code sample. But, still didn't get how could I build a job jar.

I'm following also these videos that explain how to run a job in EMR http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cAZur5maWZE&list=PL080E1DEBCE5388F3

But they didn't tell also how to get this important jar file to start the work.

Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the java files in eclipse, add hadoop to build path, then export it as a jar. See "6.1 Creating the Jar file" in this tutorial for details: [Introduction to Amazon Web Services
and MapReduce Jobs](http://snap.stanford.edu/class/cs341-2013/downloads/amazon-emr-tutorial.pdf)

And there are two ways to launch the job flow, through console or CLI, check the 6.2, 6.3 in the tutorial above.

Answer (score 2):

The same as for normal java program (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html):

```
$ javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java 
$ jar -cvf /usr/joe/wordcount.jar -C wordcount_classes/ .
```

or if it is a maven project:

```
$ mvn clean package
```

or specific for https://github.com/ScaleUnlimited/wikipedia-ngrams (see README):

```
$ ant clean job
```

Comment: Ok, they said that I should run this in my local machine. However it didn't work. Is it because windows?

Comment: Yes, you should build jar file on local machine and then upload it to S3. Windows is not problem because java is crossplatform but it may be needed to set development environment properly.